# Unable to access a csv file in Google Colaboratory

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, import-csv, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colaboratory to run my machine learning project. I wanted to import .csv into pandas and use it for further processing, but I am facing an error stating that the file is not found. Do I need to provide any authorization to access that file or is it mandatory to upload file into google colab? That file already exists in same folder on Google Drive as that of .ipynb notebook.

Code: [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) `read_csv` function to read file 
[image: pandas read_csv function to read file]

Error: Unable to locate 
[image: Unable to locate]

Do I need to provide any authentication or something like that?

Comment: I think this answer would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340341/read-csv-to-dataframe-in-google-colab

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read csv to dataframe in google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340341/read-csv-to-dataframe-in-google-colab)

Answer (score 3):

See the [I/O sample notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb) for examples showing how to work with local files and those stored on Drive.