# Importing uploaded Data into Google Collab Jupyter

Tags: google-colaboratory

How to import the dataset I have already uploaded, to my Google Collab Juypter notebook?

I have successufully uploaded my data using:
google.colab.files method

```
uploaded = files.upload()
```

But when I try to read the uploaded data(Here train.csv) , it throws FileNotFound error

```
df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
```

Maybe the files by default are getting stored in some other directory. 
Any sugesstions on how do I import my data?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Please take a look at [Local file system](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb&scrollTo=eikfzi8ZT_rW).

Comment: @srig It just mentions how to upload and download a file. I have already uploaded the file sucessfully using : Uploading files from your local file system. What I want is to import my uploaded file into my code

Comment: Issue resolved thank you

Comment: Can I import files already in my google drive. I don't want to upload files from the local system but from files already in the cloud or google drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is identical to this answered question --
[read csv to dataframe in google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340341/read-csv-to-dataframe-in-google-colab/48345619#48345619)

The file data is in `uploaded['train.csv']`, which you'll want to wrap in a `StringIO`.